# Querying geometry data (polygon and multipolygon) using Hive

Tags: hive, geospatial

I have a large dataset in csv files in blob storage that includes GPS coordinates. I have converted us census tiger shape files of US states to geojson and then to csv using ogr2ogr so I now have a csv file with polygon and multipolygon data in a geometry column. With Hive queries, ow can I join on tables pointing at these sets of csv files so I can identify the US state for each coordinate?